# How to properly embed a copy of mongoid document inside parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have Mongoid classes defined like this (irrelevant fields left out for brevity):

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :category
end

class Order
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :order_items
end

class OrderItem
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :product
  embedded_in :order

  field :count, type: Integer
end
```

That means, I keep products in separate collection and when a user makes a purchase, I want to embed copies of all products she bought inside the order document (so I have a snapshot of the exact item she bought and future edits don't alter products that have already been bought).
Is this correct way of making embedded copies or should I change my schema? For example create new document class, something like `EmbeddedProduct` and copy relevant fields from `Product`?

Current solution seems to work, but from what I read in the documentation and forums it seems that document should be either embedded or in separate collection, not both.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to get no attention whatsoever :)

Anyway, I figured the best way to go will be not to embed product in order_item, but copy relevant fields from product to order_item.

**Solution looks like this**

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document

  # product fields like name, price, ...

  belongs_to :category
end

class Order
  include Mongoid::Document

  # order fields like date, total_amount, address ...

  embeds_many :order_items
end

class OrderItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::MoneyField

  embedded_in :order

  # you can also store reference to original product
  belongs_to :original_product

  field :count, type: Integer
  field :name
  field :ean
  field :sku
  money_field :final_price

  def self.from_product(product)
    item = self.new
    # ... assign fields from product, eg: 
    # item.name = product.name

    item
  end
end
```

And when user clicks "Add to cart" you can do something like this:

```
def add
  # check if product is already in the cart
  order_item = @order.items.detect {|item| item.product_id == params[:product_id]}

  # if not, create from product in database
  if order_item.nil?
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    order_item = OrderItem.from_product(product)

    # and add to items array
    @order.items.push(order_item)
  end

  # set count that we got from product form
  # (we can do this since order_item is 
  # also reference to the order_item inside array of order_items)
  order_item.count = params[:count]

  # emit event
  event = Events::CartItemChanged.new(order_item: order_item, order: @order, request_params: params)
  broadcast :cart_item_changed, event

  # no need to call validations since we're just adding an item
  @order.save! :validate => false

  redirect_to cart_path
end
```

Comment: Beef this up a little by visualizing what happens, then feel free to accept your own answer.